# How to filter IQueryable by a new field

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable, ef-core-5.0

I must set a filter by DocumentsUnread > 0 only if the parameter filter from frontend is true, otherwise I return all the EmployeeListItem from the query. The DocumentUnread field is make by subtraction of two other fields, it's not present in the table DB, and DocumentCount is make by Count method.

```cs
public async Task<EmployeeList> GetEmployeesDownloadStatus(int pageNumber, string searchText, bool filter)
{
    int pageSize = 10;

    IQueryable<EmployeeListItem> employees = 
        from e in context.Employees
        join u in context.Users on e.EmployeeId equals u.Employee.EmployeeId
        join d in context.EmployeeDocuments on e.EmployeeId equals d.EmployeeId into dj
        from d in dj.DefaultIfEmpty()

        where 
        string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchText) ||
            (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchText) && (e.FirstName).Contains(searchText)) ||
            (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchText) && (e.LastName).Contains(searchText)) ||
            (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchText) && (e.FiscalCode).Contains(searchText)) ||
            (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchText) && (e.IdentificationNumber).Contains(searchText))
        group new { e, d, u } by new { e.EmployeeId, e.FirstName, e.LastName, e.FiscalCode, e.IdentificationNumber, e.EmploymentStartDate, u.LastAccessDate } into g
        orderby g.Key.FirstName, g.Key.LastName


        select new EmployeeListItem
        {
            EmployeeId = g.Key.EmployeeId,
            FirstName = g.Key.FirstName,
            LastName = g.Key.LastName,
            FiscalCode = g.Key.FiscalCode,
            IdentificationNumber = g.Key.IdentificationNumber,
            EmploymentStartDate = g.Key.EmploymentStartDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
            DocumentCount = g.Count(),
            DocumentOpened = g.Sum(s => s.d.DownloadedByEmployee ? 1 : 0),
            DocumentsUnread = g.Count() - g.Sum(s => s.d.DownloadedByEmployee ? 1 : 0),
            LastAccessDate = g.Key.LastAccessDate
        };

    decimal total = Convert.ToDecimal(employees.Count()) / Convert.ToDecimal(pageSize);

    EmployeeList EmployeeList = new BusinessLogic.Dto.EmployeeList
    {
        TotalPagesNumber = decimal.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(total)),
        Employees = await employees.Skip(pageNumber * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync()
    };
    return EmployeeList;
}
```

I tried to use `.Where(item => item.DocumentsUnread > 0).` before Skip method but I have this error

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Employee>()
    .Join(
        inner: DbSet<User>()
            .LeftJoin(
                inner: DbSet<Employee>(), 
                outerKeySelector: u => EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(u, "EmployeeId"), 
                innerKeySelector: e0 => EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(e0, "EmployeeId"), 
                resultSelector: (o, i) => new TransparentIdentifier<User, Employee>(
                    Outer = o, 
                    Inner = i
                )), 
        outerKeySelector: e => e.EmployeeId, 
        innerKeySelector: u => u.Inner.EmployeeId, 
        resultSelector: (e, u) => new TransparentIdentifier<Employee, TransparentIdentifier<User, Employee>>(
            Outer = e, 
            Inner = u
        ))
    .LeftJoin(
        inner: DbSet<EmployeeDocument>(), 
        outerKeySelector: ti => ti.Outer.EmployeeId, 
        innerKeySelector: e1 => e1.EmployeeId, 
        resultSelector: (ti, e1) => new TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<Employee, TransparentIdentifier<User, Employee>>, EmployeeDocument>(
            Outer = ti, 
            Inner = e1
        ))
    .Where(ti0 => False || True && ti0.Outer.Outer.FirstName.Contains(__searchText_0) || True && ti0.Outer.Outer.LastName.Contains(__searchText_0) || True && ti0.Outer.Outer.FiscalCode.Contains(__searchText_0) || True && ti0.Outer.Outer.IdentificationNumber.Contains(__searchText_0))
    .GroupBy(
        keySelector: ti0 => new { 
            EmployeeId = ti0.Outer.Outer.EmployeeId, 
            FirstName = ti0.Outer.Outer.FirstName, 
            LastName = ti0.Outer.Outer.LastName, 
            FiscalCode = ti0.Outer.Outer.FiscalCode, 
            IdentificationNumber = ti0.Outer.Outer.IdentificationNumber, 
            EmploymentStartDate = ti0.Outer.Outer.EmploymentStartDate, 
            LastAccessDate = ti0.Outer.Inner.Outer.LastAccessDate
         }, 
        elementSelector: ti0 => new { 
            e = ti0.Outer.Outer, 
            d = ti0.Inner, 
            u = ti0.Outer.Inner.Outer
         })
    .OrderBy(e2 => e2.Key.FirstName)
    .ThenBy(e2 => e2.Key.LastName)
    .Select(e2 => new EmployeeListItem{ 
        EmployeeId = e2.Key.EmployeeId, 
        FirstName = e2.Key.FirstName, 
        LastName = e2.Key.LastName, 
        FiscalCode = e2.Key.FiscalCode, 
        IdentificationNumber = e2.Key.IdentificationNumber, 
        EmploymentStartDate = e2.Key.EmploymentStartDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), 
        DocumentCount = e2
            .Count(), 
        DocumentOpened = e2
            .Sum(s => s.d.DownloadedByEmployee ? 1 : 0), 
        DocumentsUnread = e2
            .Count() - e2
            .Sum(s => s.d.DownloadedByEmployee ? 1 : 0), 
        LastAccessDate = e2.Key.LastAccessDate 
    }
    )
    .Where(e3 => e3.DocumentsUnread > 0)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

I tried to use remove method from EmployeeList but this make problem with pagination.

I should translate to linq this:

```sql
having COUNT(*) - COALESCE(SUM(CASE
    WHEN [e1].[DownloadedByEmployee] = CAST(1 AS bit) THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END), 0)>0
```

I tested it and works but i don't know how to do the same with linq.

Thanks for the help and I hope I explained the question correctly

Comment: You definitely can apply `Where` extension method on `IQueryable<T>`, check your usings section, maybe something missing.

Comment: is this Entity Framework? which version?

Comment: Yes, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore Version 5.0.1

Comment: Try to put filter before projection, maybe EF cannot translate that

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.where(item => !filter || item.DocumentsUnread > 0)`.

If the filter parameter is false, the `item.DocumentsUnread > 0` wil not be check.

Comment: EmployeeList EmployeeList = new BusinessLogic.Dto.EmployeeList
                {
                    TotalPagesNumber = decimal.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(total)),
                    Employees = await employees.where(item => !filter || item.DocumentsUnread > 0).Skip(pageNumber * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync()
                };          Like this?

Comment: Sadly it returns the same error. thank you

Comment: Try to add where clause after the group :

`where !filter || g.Count() - g.Sum(s => s.d.DownloadedByEmployee ? 1 : 0) > 0`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help!
I resolved in this way:

```
        public async Task<EmployeeList> GetEmployeesDownloadStatus(int pageNumber, string searchText, bool showOnlyDocumentsUnread)
        {
            int pageSize = 10;

            IQueryable<EmployeeListItem> employees = from e in context.Employees
                                                     join u in context.Users on e.EmployeeId equals u.Employee.EmployeeId
                                                     join d in context.EmployeeDocuments on e.EmployeeId equals d.EmployeeId into dj
                                                     from d in dj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                     group new { e, d, u } by new { e.EmployeeId, e.FirstName, e.LastName, e.FiscalCode, e.IdentificationNumber, e.EmploymentStartDate, u.LastAccessDate } into g
                                                     where string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchText) ||
                                                           (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchText) && (g.Key.FirstName).Contains(searchText) ||
                                                           (g.Key.LastName).Contains(searchText) ||
                                                           (g.Key.FiscalCode).Contains(searchText) ||
                                                           (g.Key.IdentificationNumber).Contains(searchText)) &&
                                                           (!showOnlyDocumentsUnread || g.Count() - g.Sum(s => s.d.DownloadedByEmployee ? 1 : 0) > 0)
                                                     orderby g.Key.FirstName, g.Key.LastName
                                                     select new EmployeeListItem
                                                     {
                                                         EmployeeId = g.Key.EmployeeId,
                                                         FirstName = g.Key.FirstName,
                                                         LastName = g.Key.LastName,
                                                         FiscalCode = g.Key.FiscalCode,
                                                         IdentificationNumber = g.Key.IdentificationNumber,
                                                         EmploymentStartDate = g.Key.EmploymentStartDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
                                                         DocumentCount = g.Count(),
                                                         DocumentOpened = g.Sum(s => s.d.DownloadedByEmployee ? 1 : 0),
                                                         DocumentsUnread = g.Count() - g.Sum(s => s.d.DownloadedByEmployee ? 1 : 0),
                                                         LastAccessDate = g.Key.LastAccessDate
                                                     };

                decimal total = Convert.ToDecimal(employees.Count()) / Convert.ToDecimal(pageSize);
                EmployeeList EmployeeList = new BusinessLogic.Dto.EmployeeList
                {
                    TotalPagesNumber = decimal.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(total)),
                    Employees = await employees.Skip(pageNumber * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync()
                };
                return EmployeeList;
        }
```